# Process terminated with status -1073741571 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))

Tags: c++, c++17

After building this code, I get this error: Process terminated with status -1073741571 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)). So what should I do to solve this problem?

I'm using Code::Blocks 16.01. I have tried many times but always get this error. But if this code is run on Ideone, it is okay.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
struct matrix
{
    ll val[3005][3005];
    ll row, col;
};
matrix operator * (matrix a, matrix b)
{
    matrix res;
    if(a.col != b.row)
        return res;
    for(ll i = 1; i <= a.row; i++)
        for(ll j = 1; j <= b.col; j++)
            for(ll k = 1; k <= a.col; k++)
                   res.val[i][j] = res.val[i][j] + a.val[i][k] * b.val[k] 
[j];
    res.row = a.row; res.col = b.col;
    return res;
}
matrix a,b,c;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    cin>>a.row>>a.col>>b.row>>b.col;
    for(ll i = 1; i <= a.row; i++)
        for(ll j = 1; j <= a.col; j++)
            cin>>a.val[i][j];
    for(ll i = 1; i <= b.row; i++)
        for(ll j = 1; j <= b.col; j++)
            cin>>b.val[i][j];
    c = a * b;
    for(ll i = 1; i <= c.row; i++)
    {
        for(ll j = 1; j <= c.col; j++)
            cout<<c.val[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: In general you should debug with gdb to get much more detailed error information.

Comment: My guess would be, `matrix` is too large to be placed on the stack, as a local variable. The size of the stack is limited. The program probably encounters a stack overflow.

Comment: So `0xC00000FD` which is what that number translates to in hex, also corresponds to `NT_STATUS` of `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik based on that status code I'd guess you're right

Comment: So you're trying to allocate about 72.2 MB of space on the stack. Which is larger than any default stack on most systems.

Comment: What input do you input? `for(ll i = 1; i <= c.row; i++)` worries me - in C++ arrays are indexed starting from 0, not from 1. If You input maximum possible row and column size (3005), then you will overflow memory.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I reduced the size of val[][] and it works now! Thank you very much.

Comment: 9,030,025 elements in that array!

Comment: Also btw your code is very hard to read. Try some comments!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I disagree, the code is very clear. The only problems are 1) lack of spaces (`cin>>a.val[i][j];` should be `cin >> a.val[i][j];`) 2) multiple statements per line (`res.row = a.row; res.col = b.col;` and `cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);`).

Comment: @dyukha You and I have very different definitions of "very clear", friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some previous comments mentioned, you're most likely running into a stack overflow issue here.  The default stack size of a thread is platform dependent, so it makes sense that your code would result in a crash in certain environments, but work in others.

A possible way to have caught this issue would have been running it with [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) enabled.  For example (I have your code in "main.cc"):

```
$ g++ main.cc
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
$ g++ -fsanitize=address main.cc
$ ./a.out
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==224881==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffc3567b098 (pc 0x5586c57fe932 bp 0x7ffc39b5fd40 sp 0x7ffc3567b0a0 T0)
    #0 0x5586c57fe931 in main (~/a.out+0x2931)
    #1 0x7fddf00c052a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2352a)
    #2 0x5586c57fe509 in _start (~/a.out+0x2509)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (~/a.out+0x2931) in main
==224881==ABORTING
```

For educational purposes only (I do *NOT* recommend actually doing this), we can observe your program working if we manually increase the stack limit.  On Linux, if we insert

```
struct HackRunBeforeMain {
  HackRunBeforeMain() {
    // See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html
    // Not checking any errors to keep the example simple.
    struct rlimit rlim;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim);
    // Set the current thread's stack size to 1GB!
    rlim.rlim_cur = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim);
  }
};
HackRunBeforeMain hack_run_before_main;
```

into your program, running it does not result in a segfault (at least on my machine).

For a long term fix, you should look into ensuring that each `matrix`'s data is on the heap, rather than the stack.  You can accomplish this via tools such as `malloc`, `new`, or `std::make_unique<T>`.  Modifying the original program to do so is left as an exercise to the asker.